# Code is not converting uppercase letter to lowercase when preceeded by a vowel

Tags: c++, string

[Codeforces Problem-](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/118/A/)

When I give an input of uppercase preceeded by a vowel ,it is not converting the uppercase letter into lowercase
e-g-Input-aBAcAba
output-.B.c.b

```
int main() 
{
    int i;
    locale loc;
    string a;
    cin>>a;
    for(i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        if(isupper(a[i]))
            a[i]=tolower(a[i]);
        if(a[i]=='a'||a[i]=='e'||a[i]=='i'||a[i]=='o'||a[i]=='u')
        {
            a.erase(a.begin()+i);
        }
        if(a[i]=='a'||a[i]=='e'||a[i]=='i'||a[i]=='o'||a[i]=='u')
            i--;
    }
    for(i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        cout<<'.'<<a[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your second condition will always be false because at that point you already erased the vowel, so i-- is never executed.

Comment: actually in my opinion the size after erasing shrink automatically and on ith position there will be the element which is next in string

Comment: Sorry I was wrong,Yes you are right ...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(a[i]=='a'||a[i]=='e'||a[i]=='i'||a[i]=='o'||a[i]=='u')
 i--;
```

This doesn't work, because you have already erased the vowel from `a`, so the decrement doesn't happen and you skip the next character.

You might instead want to do

```
if (condition)
   a.erase(...);
else
   ++i;
```

and remove the increment from the for-statement.